# AOS not triggering animation in view with Astro component

Tags: javascript, animation, astrojs, aos.js

My Astro component triggers [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) (Animate on Scroll) only once and not when in view. Here's my astro component:

```
---
import { Image } from '@astrojs/image/components';
import CTA from './common/CTA.astro';

const IMAGE_SIZE = 500;
---

<div
  class="relative bg-[url('src/assets/images/salon.jpg')] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
>
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-black/75"></div>
  <Image src="src/assets/images/logo.png" width={IMAGE_SIZE} height={IMAGE_SIZE} alt="Barber Studio" />
  <h1 class="hidden">Barber Studio</h1>
  <div data-aos="fade-up" class="relative w-full z-1 text-center -translate-y-11">
    <CTA />
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  import AOS from 'aos';

  AOS.init();

</script>
```

I've correctly implemented the CSS but the animation is not retriggered on view. I've not found any relevant information online.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems like you are exporting a function called `AOSInit` that calls `AOS.init()`. However, you never call that function. You should either call `AOS.init()` outside of `AOSInit` or call `AOSInit`

Comment: Yep you're right, but even when I change it to `AOS.init()` the animation only triggers once. I've even tried `AOS.refresh()` but with no success.

Comment: Well its working but only triggers once and not when in view.